# OSGI runtime cannot pull dependencies from my local repository

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-camel, osgi-bundle, fuseesb

I am working on a camel project and am trying to package the project as a osgi bundle and deploy on a Fuse ESB container which uses karaf.

The POM File is reproduced below.

When I tried a `mvn install`, I got a couple of unresolved package errors. So, I included them in the manifest entries using 'Import-Package' within the POM. This cleared the errors and the bundle got created but when I try to deploy it on fuse container, the bundle stops with an error `Unable to resolve 257.0: missing requirement [257.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.i2.cis.api.connector)`.

Does this mean that the osgi runtime is not able to pull these jars which are in my local .m2 repository?

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.abc.cde</groupId>
<artifactId>x2xx</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<name>Test</name>
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <camel.osgi.export.pkg />
  <camel.version>2.12.2</camel.version>
  <activemq.version>5.9.0</activemq.version>
  <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  <build.number>SNAPSHOT</build.number>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <!-- the cis libraries are present in this repo -->
    <repository>
        <id>repo</id>
        <name>test</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <!-- Start : CIS dependencies from local repo  -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>cis</groupId>
      <artifactId>cis</artifactId>
      <version>8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>cis</groupId>
      <artifactId>cis-util</artifactId>
      <version>8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>cis</groupId>
      <artifactId>cis-sso-spi</artifactId>
      <version>8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>cis</groupId>
      <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>cis</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
      <version>8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- End : CIS dependencies from local repo  -->

  <dependency>
      <groupId>xalan</groupId>
      <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Start : Camel Jars -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
  </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-cache</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
      <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
  </dependency>
  <!-- stream input -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- End : Camel Jars -->

  <!-- Start : Spring Jars -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- End : Spring Jars -->

  <!-- Start : Testing Jars -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>de.theess.juxy</groupId>
      <artifactId>juxy</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- End : Testing Jars -->

  <!-- logging -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Start : Active MQ Jars-->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
      <version>${activemq.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
      <version>${activemq.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- End : Active MQ Jars-->

</dependencies>

<build>
  <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
  <finalName>tma-1x</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <check>
                <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
            </check>
            <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
            <formats>
                <format>xml</format>
            </formats>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>cobertura</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-jaxb-index</id>
                <!-- here the phase you need -->
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/classes/com/example/abc/bean</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/java/com/abc/cde/bean</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>jaxb.index</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <effort>Max</effort>
            <threshold>Low</threshold>
            <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>findbugs</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.7</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <instructions>
          <Bundle-SymbolicName>oo-test</Bundle-SymbolicName>
          <Private-Package>com.abc.cde.*</Private-Package>
          <Import-Package>
            com.xx.cis.api.connector, 
            com.xx.cis.connector.client, 
            javax.resource, 
            javax.resource.cci, 
            javax.xml.bind, 
            javax.xml.bind.annotation, 
            javax.xml.namespace, 
            org.apache.activemq, 
            org.apache.activemq.camel.component, 
            org.apache.activemq.pool, 
            org.apache.camel, 
            org.apache.camel.builder, 
            org.apache.camel.component.jms, 
            org.apache.camel.impl, 
            org.apache.camel.model, 
            org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate, 
            org.apache.camel.spi, 
            org.apache.camel.spring, 
            org.apache.camel.spring.spi, 
            org.apache.commons.pool, 
            org.apache.commons.pool.impl, 
            org.slf4j, 
            org.springframework.beans, 
            org.springframework.beans.factory.config, 
            org.springframework.context, 
            org.springframework.jms.connection, 
            org.w3c.dom
          </Import-Package>
        </instructions>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<description></description>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that your bundle imports the package `com.i2.cis.api.connector` but that no bundle exports that package (at the appropriate version) and therefore your bundle cannot be resolved. For each requirement (e.g. package import) there must be a matching capability (e.g. package export).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install all required bundles together with your own bundle. For this Karaf uses feature files. You might want to create that for your project. 
Details about the right provisioning with Karaf can be found in the [documentation](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/provisioning.html) of it.